# What exactly is an early adopter version - SQL Developer?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I notice that the current version of SQL developer is "Early adopter 3.0".  Is this just a fancy name for a Beta release or a GA release, RC or whatever the name is this week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle runs proper Beta programmes for its licensed software - the database, app server, e-Business Suite, etc.  Those programemes are closed,  invitation-only affairs.

But it also has a raft of fringe products for which it doesn't charge, things such as SQL Developer, JDeveloper, Application Express, SQL Dev Data Modeler, etc.  These products have built-up enthusiastic communities.  Oracle leverages their fervour to defray the cost of beta testing by releasing Early Adopter and/or Release Candidate versions of the software.  In return the Early Adoptors get access to new features they need, and perhaps the opportunity to shape the products while the software is still malleable.

In general "Early Adopter" indicates something which is still in the process of being finished i.e. it may lack features which are scheduled for the production version.   "Release Candidate" is software which is basically complete but has some unpolished functionality and known, unresolved bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a beta release, or maybe a release candidate.

"Early adopter" makes people feel better about being unpaid testers.

Incidentally, "GA" means "General Availability", i.e. a proper, full release.

Comment: My spelling is not that good at all, so if I can help someone else, I don't feel as bad about all the help I require.